# How do I display data from table2 via table1 using mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, `directory`, and `pictures`.  Both `directory` and `pictures` contain an ID number in column 1.  I want row 1 (ID 1) of `directory` to pull information of `pictures`.  I want it to be versatile, i.e. if I pull ID 2 from `directory` it will show ID 2 from `pictures`.

I want `directory.ID` to pull `Pictures.photo` based on ID.  Maybe this makes more sense...

Comment: "JOIN" is the magic keyword here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29

Comment: select * from directory , pictures where direcotry.id = pictures.id

if I understood your quesion

Comment: I'd suggest you spend a few minutes taking a [SQL tutorial](http://www.sqlcourse.com/index.html) to at least learn basic syntax and use. If the one I linked isn't to your liking, there were many others found with a Google search on `SQL tutorial`. Good luck! :-)

Answer (score 2):

For this purpose you should use a [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

```
select * 
from directory d
JOIN pictures p ON d.ID = p.ID
```